# Symfony Sonata project: How to add multiple input texts to block?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I would like to add a collection of input text with same name (i.e. name="blabla[]") filed to admin **block** with add/delete buttons.

I'm using `collection` form field type but can't see add/delete buttons

```
public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
{
    $formMapper->add('settings', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
        'keys' => array(
            array('title', 'collection', 
                array('type' => 'text' ,
                    'required' => true,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'data' => array('First' => 'One')
                    )
                )
        )
    ));
}
```

I get below result without add/delete buttons!
[image]

Any idea how to get it working ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `sonata_type_collection` or `sonata_type_native_collection` instead of `collection`.

Here is an extract of the [field doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection) :

> 14.1.7. SONATA_TYPE_NATIVE_COLLECTION (PREVIOUSLY COLLECTION)
>
> This bundle handle the native Symfony collection form type by adding:
>
> an add button if you set the allow_add option to true. a delete button
>   if you set the allow_delete option to true.

Comment: I tried "sonata_type_collection" before and it shows "Impossible to access an attribute ("mappingtype") on a null variable in SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig at line 151". sonata_type_native_collection worked! thanks for the answer.

Comment: You've to override the options with those given in the doc (ex: type_options)